# Mapping rows of a Pandas dataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Sorry, I know there are so many questions relating to indexing, and it's probably starring me in the face, but I'm having a little trouble with this. I am familiar with `.loc`, `.iloc`, and `.index` methods and slicing in general. The method `.reset_index` may not have been (and may not be able to be) called on our dataframe and therefore index lables may not be in order. The dataframe and numpy array(s) are actually different length subsets of the dataframe, but for this example I'll keep them the same size (I can handle offsetting once I have an example).

Here is a picture that show's what I'm looking for:
[image]

I can pull cols of rows from the dataframe based on some search criteria.

```
idxlbls = df.index[df['timestamp'] == dt]
stuff = df.loc[idxlbls, 'col3':'col5']
```

But how do I map that to row number (array indices, not label indices) to be used as an array index in numpy (assuming same row length)?

```
stuffprime = array[?, ?]
```

The reason I need it is because the dataframe is much larger and more complete and contains the column searching criteria, but the numpy arrays are subsets that have been extracted and modified prior in the pipeline (and do not have the same searching criteria in them). I need to search the dataframe and pull the equivalent data from the numpy arrays. Basically I need to correlate specific rows from a dataframe to the corresponding rows of a numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions by filtered columns names, for index is possible use same way or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for positions by boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':list('abadef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]}, index=list('ABCDEF'))

print (df)
  timestamp  B  C  D  E
A         a  4  7  1  5
B         b  5  8  3  3
C         a  4  9  5  6
D         d  5  4  7  9
E         e  5  2  1  2
F         f  4  3  0  4

idxlbls = df.index[df['timestamp'] == 'a']
stuff = df.loc[idxlbls, 'C':'E']
print (stuff)
   C  D  E
A  7  1  5
C  9  5  6

a = df.index.get_indexer(stuff.index)
```

Or get positions by boolean mask:

```
a = np.where(df['timestamp'] == 'a')[0]

print (a)
[0 2]
```

---

```
b = df.columns.get_indexer(stuff.columns)
print (b)
[2 3 4]
```

Comment: `stuff.rows` instead of `stuff.columns` ?

Comment: @delrocco - No, in pandas it is `stuff.index`, `stuff.rows` is in new versions of pandas not implemented (maybe in some oldier, not sure)

Comment: very sorry, still confused... I need rows 2 and 4 only from `stuffprime` (the numpy array, not the dataframe)

Comment: @delrocco - I think need `np.where(df['timestamp'] == dt)[0]`

Comment: ok, I see that. are you sure those values `[0 2]` will be row numbers even if the dataframe index column is shuffled?

Comment: @delrocco - Sure, try it.

Comment: thank you very much! I can work with that to get what I really need now lol thx!

Answer (score 1):

I would map pandas indices to numpy indicies:

```
keys_dict = dict(zip(idxlbls, range(len(idxlbls))))
```

Then you may use the dictionary `keys_dict` to address the array elements by a pandas index: `array[keys_dict[some_df_index], :]`